# Nested Connections in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I recently created a light weight ORM tool in C# and posted it on github. https://www.github.com/RiceRiceBaby/ADOCRUD. One of the things my ORM does is manage the opening and closing of connections for you. The way I do this is I open the connection in the constructor of my context class and close it on dispose. The code below is an example of how to use my tool.

```
using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString)
{
     context.Insert<Product>(p);
     context.Commit();
}
```

The problem with me implementing this automatic management of connection is that  it prevents nested connections from working. For example, the following will not work:

```
public Product GetProductById(int productId)
{
  Product p = null;

  using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString))
  {
    p = context.QueryItems<Product>("select * from dbo.Product where Id = @id", new { id = productId }).FirstOrDefault();
  }

  return p;
}

public void UpdateProduct(int productId)
{
  using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString))
  {
    Product p = this.GetProductById(productId);
    p.Name = "Basketball";
    context.Update<Product>(p);
    context.Commit();
  }
}
```

The reason this won't work is because the last brace in the using statement of the method `GetProductId` method will close the sql connections for both `GetProductId` context and `UpdateProduct` context. This means that `context.Update<Product>(p);` will throw an exception because the connection has already been closed.

I thought this automatic management of connections is a good idea but I'm afraid people might not use my tool if they don't have the ability to have nested connections. Is there a way to keep this management of connections while allowing nested connections like the code above?

Comment: It seems like you are creating separate `ADOCRUDContext` instances. If I've understood your design you'd be creating two connections with the `UpdateProduct` call. If so they can close independently of each other.

Comment: Hi Enigmativity. I've been looking at my code and thats exactly what should have happened, but for some reason, when I debugged, context.Update<Product>(p) threw an exception saying the connection was closed. My assumption is because the context in the GetProductById method closed its own connection and the other one and I dont' know why.

Comment: I think you need to post the code for the full `ADOCRUDContext` class.

Comment: I had a look at the ADOCRUDContext class and noticed that the connection is hold in a **static** class variable. While this might work, wouldn't it be better to use a not regular member variable?

Comment: Don't reuse connections. Don't share connections. Just Open, run command, close. Let connection pooling deal with sharing actual connections in the background. The only thing that should be shared around is the connection *string*. And that can be freely shared without issues.

Comment: @user2900970 - Yes, the `static` variable would be the problem. That's why we need to see all of the code.

Comment: @Enigmativity - even though my sqlconnection variable is static, the class (ADOCRUDContext) that holds it is not. That means that a different instance should use a different connection from the connection pool every time.

Comment: @RandomAsianGuy - Well, the connection being `static` is clearly your problem. And it's the reason why we ask for all the code to be posted. Actually we ask for a [mcve], but the idea is the same.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity. It looks like I was wrong. I wrote a unit test that proved your theory was right. I didn't realize a static property of 2 different instances of an object shared the same space in memory.

Comment: @RandomAsianGuy - No worries. That's exactly what `static` is for - it's a shared variable for the class rather than each instance.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that nobody said that the first analysis of the issue is wrong.

I am right to all of your answer

- multiple **using** will cause bugs like in this case
- use separated connections
- use factory

Ok ok but the first issue of this code is just the object

```
Product p = this.GetProductById(productId);
```

will lose its context and the first using want to use a disconnected object and that is forbidden. But if you attached this object to the first context opened you can reuse it and do your **Update**.

To summarize, you have these steps

1. USING, open 1st context
2. call to GetProductById
3. USING 2nd context
4. Get the product in the 2nd context
5. Close and Dispose 2nd context
6. Update properties of Product returned in the 1st context
7. Update product in the 1st context
8. **ERROR:** the product returned is disconnected

Now you must have

1. USING, open 1st context
2. call to GetProductById
3. USING 2nd context
4. Get the product in the 2nd context
5. Close and Dispose 2nd context
6. Update properties of Product returned in the 1st context
7. ATTACH Product object to the first context
8. Update product in the 1st context
9. **OK** The Product is updated

Try this code to attach

```
var entry = context.Entry(entity);
if (entry != null)
{
     entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

### **EDIT**

Like we discuss in comments, the issue comes from the source code of [*ADOCRUDContext*](https://github.com/RiceRiceBaby/ADOCRUD/blob/master/ADOCRUD/ADOCRUDContext.cs)

The member sqlConnection and sqlTransaction are marked **static** and should not.

Correction was done when I wrote these lines. It is just to marked as solution for others

Comment: Do you assume that context is a EF DbContext? Thats wrong, OP wrote its own ADOCRUDContext.

Comment: Ok my mess. I haven't see the github link project. After see the source code why don't you work on Dispose method on Context object to manage connection closure, etc ...

Comment: My dispose method does manage connection closure. I have it set up that it should only be closing the connection it opened. For some reason, its closing multiple connections.

Comment: Its is not for some reasons ^^ you have a static member for your connection so I suppose it closed the only connection available as I remark in your source code

Comment: Even though the connection property is static, the class containing it is not static. So every time you instantiate a new instance of the ADOCRUDContext, it should open a new connection with that instance every time and it should close that same connection on dispose. It shouldn't be closing every connection which is what it is doing. Please tell me if I am in error about this.

Comment: Sure not. A static property is shared by every object. When you're class is discovered the static property is init. When you instantiate the first ADOCRUDContext, the property is set by the constructor. But if you instantiate direclty another one, you can compare them, you will have the same between two instances. That what is specified 'static'. And like it does in your code, you will have 'ghost' connections but on that I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I tested what you said and you were definitely right. Once I took off the static, the nested connections worked like a charm on my unit tests. If you could edit your post above to the correct answer, I'll mark your post as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this post as solution for other people who have the same issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use *reference counting* to keep track of how many using statements the code goes through and to properly close the context at the right time, and then a single using statement on the outside of a block with multiple database calls will force the use of the same context instance.

```
using (var context = this.contextManager.GetContext(connectionString))
{
    var product = DL.GetProductById(id);
    product.name = "The Best Product";
    DL.UpdateProduct(product);
}
```

You can see an example of reference counting in the [CSLA DbContextManager Class](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/blob/master/Source/Csla.Data.EF7.Shared/DbContextManager.cs).

However, many modern applications use a dependency injection container to control the lifetime of the DB Context. So it would make sense if there were a way to do it that way as an alternative to reference counting (actually, your current ADOCRUDContext would probably work if it were injected into the constructor of the classes that use it, but it might make sense to wrap the connection string into another object so it can be injected without explicit configuration, and swapped more easily).

Also, many would argue that having to new up your ADOCRUDContext inline is anti-pattern because there is no way to mock the context (hence, no way to test it). A way around that would be to use an [abstract factory pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/) to allow injecting the context into the class.

Comment: Hmm...so you are saying let the user inject a connection into the context and the class will open the connection, perform the database calls, and the close the connection?

Comment: Reference counting is one way to do it that will work whether using a DI container or not. I recommend reading the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) for ideas about dealing with dependency injection. There is a section that goes over this exact scenario (DB context) in detail and a chapter that tells how to deal with `IDisposable`, and also examples in the code download with the book. Its much more detailed than any answer I could provide here.

Answer (score 0):

No, do not create some magic which would allow your example code to function over multiple `using` statements as that's not expected. A `using` statement is created just to be able to control the cleanup/lifetime of the object.

If you bypass that, you take way the control from your user.

The most sane approach is to simply pass the context in the class constructor (or simply create the context in the constructor). By doing so, all methods would share the same context.

The other approach is to do something like `TransactionScope`. i.e. be able to share an internal scope but also be able to explicitly tell if a new scope is required.

```
public Product GetProductById(int productId)
{
  Product p = null;

  using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString))
  {
    p = context.QueryItems<Product>("select * from dbo.Product where Id = @id", new { id = productId }).FirstOrDefault();
  }

  return p;
}

public void UpdateProduct(int productId)
{
  //see the second argument
  using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString, Options.ReuseExisting))
  {
    Product p = this.GetProductById(productId);
    p.Name = "Basketball";
    context.Update<Product>(p);
    context.Commit();
  }
}
```

However, that requires you to deal with `[ThreadStatic]` variable within your `ADOCRUDContext` that keeps track of the currently open context. Do note that `[ThreadStatic]` do not work very well with TPL/Tasks. Thus this approach is much more complex since you need to be aware of how different threading techniques work i .NET.

Comment: Hi J. I actually implemented transaction scope into this project already in it works pretty well. I will think about your idea of somehow passing in the context to keep track of the currently open context. Thanks!